# Android default font

Tags: android, fonts

I want my app to use the default font that the phone is using, how do I do that? Currently no matter what the font settings are on my phone, the font on my app remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this magic:

```
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromFile("/system/fonts/" + sp1.getSelectedItem().toString() + ".ttf"));
```

Comment: Mind to explain this a bit?